# A button/tab looking same no matter of width

Tags: html, css, button

I am trying to achieve a button, which would look same (its background) no matter how wide it will be (the longer text inside, the wider button).

For button image i would use 1 pixel wide image:

[image] - it have 5 pixels black on top, and then 35 pixels red. And i use that css to repeat the background:

```
background-image:url('../images/button.png');
background-repeat: repeat-x;
```

Now, it will look like this: [image: xx][image: xx][image: xx][image: xx][image: xx][image: xx][image: xx][image: xx][image: xx][image: xx][image: xx][image: xx]

But i want to use these two images as a left and right side of the button:
[image] [image]
So it would like the button is curved on the top corners, and it will look like a real button. Is it even possible?

So, the question is, how can i use 3 images as a background of a div, or any other thing, to make it look like one, whole button, with middle part repeating as many times, as it needs, to fill it.
Desired look: [image]

PS. I painted that in MSPaint a sec ago, so don't mind the quality of curving, or colors, i just wanted it to be visible.

Comment: you can use tow div inside and outside one of them black and other red, and use moze-border to radius border.

Comment: Or with just one div and a border radius...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try googling this before you posted? There are many sites and examples out there on how to do this. Try searching for "css tabs with rounded corners" and see what you get...

Here are 2 links to start with, but in future try a simple Google search before posting a question.

Example Code from http://www.sitepoint.com/accessible-menu-tabs/

```
<ul id="navigation">
<li><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li><a href="page1.html"><span>Page 1</span></a></li>
</ul>

#navigation a { color: #000; background: #fb0 url("left-tab.gif") left top no-repeat; text-decoration: none; padding-left: 10px }
#navigation a span { background: url("right-tab.gif") right top no-repeat; padding-right: 10px }
#navigation a, #navigation a span { display: block; float: left } 
#navigation a:hover { color: #fff; background: #26a url("left-tab-hover.gif") left top no-repeat; text-decoration: none; padding-left: 10px }
#navigation a:hover span { background: url("right-tab-hover.gif") right top no-repeat; padding-right: 10px }
#navigation { list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0 }
#navigation li { float: left; display: block; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
```

Or a Repository of more Tutorials etc: http://www.bitrepository.com/rounded-corners-tab-menus.html

You will definitely find something to work for you there....

Comment: of course, tried a lot. Tried looking tabs tutorials, button tutorials, even tried to type something like "3 background image in css" or others :P

Comment: I used "css tabs with rounded corners" (which is exactly what you are looking for) and got lots of helpful sites on the 1st results page.  Maybe your search needs to be more specific to what you need. The sitepoint link gives you the code, and the bitrepository has lots of tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use cutting-edge CSS3 features, you could specify more than one `background-image` using CSS, but this won't work with older browsers like IE.

You could also use the `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements, but this again probably won't work in IE.

Then you could use images and float them to the right and left.

You can see each method here:
http://jsfiddle.net/xawQ8/

Comment: nice suggestion of :before and :after.

Comment: Very nice suggestion, but likeraser says, its not fully supported in IE. :before (the CSS2 notation) isn't even fully supported until IE9...!!

Answer (score 1):

Or just add the left and right side of the button to the button content.

Like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/rVaPc/
(dirty and quick code)